# Date is 01/01/0001 and not the date that is in the database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this line in my sql server 2008 r2 database, but I don't understand:

```
2012-12-06 11:00:36.703 and is of type DATETIME
```

When I display it in my view it is:

```
Mon, Jan 1, 0001
```

Here my code:

```
var allNews = ZincService.NewsService.GetNewsPostsForId(id);

List<Zinc.Web.Areas.News.ViewModels.Home.NewsPostsViewModel> newsItems = new List<NewsPostsViewModel>();

foreach (var newsItem in allNews)
{ 
  NewsPostsViewModel newsItemViewModel = new NewsPostsViewModel();
  newsItemViewModel.CommentDate = String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", newsItem.CommentDate);
}

public class NewsPostsViewModel
{
  public Entities.News.News MainNews { get; set; }
  public virtual string News { get; set; }
  public virtual int NewsId { get; set; }
  public virtual string CommentDate { get; set; }
}

  public List<DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel> GetNewsPostsForId(int id)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ZincModelContainer.CONNECTIONSTRING))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = "[News].[GetNewsPostsForId]";

      SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
      param.Value = id;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

      List<DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel> news = new List<DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel>();

      using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          string message = Convert.ToString(row["NewsDescription"]);
          news.Add(new DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel { NewsPostId = id ,Message = message});
        }
      }

      return news;
    }
  }
}

public class NewsPostsDataModel
{
  public virtual int NewsPostId { get; set; }
  public virtual string Message { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Can some one help me, please?

Comment: Well that suggests it hasn't been fetched properly. Unfortunately you haven't given us any information about how you're accessing it. We can't currently help you without more information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Is it a datetime field in the DB or varchar?

Comment: how are you fetching `newsItem.CommentDate`, currently it is showing `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: Apparently `newsItem.CommentDate` is yet not initialized since it returns [`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx).

Comment: How are you assigning the value of comment date?

You have not provided enough code/information to give an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
news.Add(new DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel { NewsPostId = id ,Message = message});
```

You're not populating `CommentDate` here, so it's got the default value of `DateTime.MinValue`.

Of course we now can't tell whether your stored procedure returns the value at all, but assuming it does, you should presumably be fetching it from the `DataRow` and putting it in your model...

Before you *just* fix the code, you should take a step back and think about your diagnostic process. Did you try debugging into this? Adding logging? You should have been able to see very quickly that you didn't have a `CommentDate` in the model, and then tried to work out *why* you didn't have a `CommentDate`, which should have led you back to the code creating the instance of the model. If you can improve your diagnostic processes, you can speed you your future development significantly by not having to ask as many questions.

Comment: @charlie_cat: Well have you validated that you've now *actually got the date* in the model? What debugging have you performed?

Comment: sorry i saw the problem as you indicated, im trying to fix it quick, thanks

Comment: my problem was in my repository var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateAndTime"]);
              news.Add(new DataModels.News.NewsPostsDataModel { NewsPostId = id ,NewsComment = message , CommentDate = dateTime});